# IONIC IOS: List simulator targets Running command: xcrun simctl list --json Select last emulator from list as default

Tags: angular, typescript, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic4

[image]

I have an ionic application that builds normally for android. It turns out that when I run the command:
 `ionic cordova build ios --prod --release`
on mac it always returns this error. Strange because two days ago I managed to run the same command on the same project. Does anyone have any idea what might be going on?
Already tried:
`sudo rm -rf node_modules`
`sudo rm -rf  platforms`
`sudo npm install`
`sudo ionic cordova platforms add ios`
 `ionic cordova build ios --prod --release`
Returns the same error...
But when I run:
`ionic serves`
it opens normally without any error.
Does anyone have any solution

Answer (score 0):

If it was working two days ago and stopped now then most likely it is an issue of some update. Most likely it is an update of Xcode, some node dependency or the node itself, or. Starting from checking if the Xcode was updated would be the best start.

Answer (score 0):

Use `cordova build ios` without sudo
It will work

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Just run command with *sudo* once and after that run same command without *sudo*

Strange but it worked for me

```
sudo cordova build ios 
cordova build ios
```